# How to use symbolic breakPoints in Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a new android APP developer and recently some problem comes. For the reason that I don't know how to use Symbolic breakpoints in Android studio when I debug the Android App. I have searched for answer on the internet but failed.
[image]

Comment: Does anyone know?

Comment: I think this will be a helpful debug function,because I have found the similar function in IOS develop toolkit.